# Unable to append bytes at the end of the file in SD card - Lollipop

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, android-download-manager, documentfile

I am building a downloading manager to download files and save it to my sd card. For API>=23, I have to use [FileOutputStream,](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) which help me to resume the file in case downloading fails. 
However, in API 21 & API 22 (Lollipop), one can't write in Sd card, but it can be done with the help of [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html).
 I am able to create files and folders in Lollipop but unable to resume downloading if the file is partially downloaded. My code is as follows:

```
if (file.exists()) {
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");

                        String s = file.getPath();
                        String s1 = getRealPathFromURI(documentFile.getUri());
                        s = s.replace(s1, "");
                        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString() + Uri.encode(s));
                        output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri2);
                    } else {
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
                        DocumentFile tempDocumentFile = documentFile.createFile("video/mp4", "temp/" + downloadsPaths.get(i));
                        output = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(tempDocumentFile.getUri());
                    }
```

It is rewriting the current file. I am looking for handling append mode in DocumentFile. I have provide all the required permissions. Help me out here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Download to internal storage first, then move the completed result to removable storage when the download is complete. Or, download to a location on removable storage that you can directly access (e.g., `getExternalCacheDirs()` 2nd entry), then move the completed result to its intended location when the download is complete.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am bound to save the downloading files in sd card only. I am dealing with huge amount of data ~4GB. And many of my users faced low internal storage issues. Also, copying this amount of data might take more than 5 min.

Comment: `use FileOutputStream, which help me to resume the file in case downloading fails.`. Why not mention that you can open a FileOutputStream in append mode and that that possibility fails while using Document.

Comment: @greenapps In order to open a file in writeable mode (API 21)  I am bound to use `openOutputStream` which help to access the files in sd card in writeable mode.

Comment: Now you really talk nonsense.